# MySQL Results a list separated by comma and values from different table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, I want to join values separated by comma and show them one field show all values that contain the id from the other table.

Example:

This is table1

```
--------------------------------------
|   id  |   title   |   area         |
| -----------------------------------|
|   1   |   hi      |   1,12,14      |
| -----------------------------------|
|   2   |   by      |   12,14,2      |
| -----------------------------------|
|   3   |   me      |   14,2         |
--------------------------------------
```

This is table2

```
---------------------
|   id  |   name    |
|-------------------|
|   1   |   Wa      |
|-------------------|
|   12  |   La      |
|-------------------|
|   14  |   Sa      |
|-------------------|
|   2   |   Tn      |
---------------------
```

And I would like to display this

```
------------------------------------
|   id  |   title   |   area       |
|----------------------------------|
|   1   |   hi      |   Wa,La,Sa   |
|----------------------------------|
|   2   |   by      |   La,Sa,Tn   |
|----------------------------------|
|   3   |   me      |   Sa,Tn      |
------------------------------------
```

Simply replacing values from table1 by the names from table2 by id.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you should create a new table named for example `table1_has_table2`

```
CREATE TABLE table1_has_table2 (
    table1_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    table2_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (table1_id,table2_id)
)
```

This then allows your n:m relationship to be performed very simply i.e.

```
SELECT 
    table1.id,
    table1.title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(table2.name) AS area

FROM table1

INNER JOIN table1_has_table2
ON table1_has_table2.table1_id = table1.id

INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.id = table1_has_table2.table2_id

GROUP BY table1.id
```

This method is also far more efficient in the long run

Comment: Should I create the table like this?
CREATE TABLE table1_has_table2 (
    table1_id INT UNSIGNED PK,
    table2_id INT UNSIGNED PK
)
Because its giving me sql syntax error.

Comment: Updated with proper SQL instead of shorthand

Comment: Its seem working but I don't get any results "MySQL returned an empty result set". Btw, table1_has_table2.table2.id need to be table1_has_table2.table2_id?

Comment: Well spotted there Dar, you are correct.  If you've implemented the suggestion and it's not returning results, please could you add an updated example?  It may be something in the implementation